# Button is not working when placed on background image?

Tags: html, css

The button is not clickable when placed on the background image?

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image:  url('assets/img/5514.jpg'); filter: brightness(200%)">
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The button is showing on the background image but is not clickable.

Comment: Problem is elsewhere... Or removing background makes the button clickable? :-) Probably the button is below another element which isn't in the code above.

Comment: _“I am new here ,need help.”_ - go read [ask] and [mre], please, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code in JS Fiddle and its working... this issue may be with image div... so try adding `z-index` to image div in `negative` and then test by adding click event to button

Visit [JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fvnc10he/)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine here. Please use this code.

HTML:-

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image:  url('assets/img/5514.jpg'); filter: brightness(200%)">
    <button onClick="alert('test')" class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Text goes here</h1>
</div>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Some table</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:-

```
.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMDk0fQ&w=1000&q=80');
}
```